# Fixing Icon Size on Browser Zoom (with Chrome)

Tags: css, font-awesome

i just found an issue on my web project and i couldnt find a way around it.
i saw something about sprites and a blog that mentions this issue.
everything looks fine on 100% but when i zoom in with my browser the icons get bigger and bigger and break the layout.

this is what my css look like

```
.Sidebar {
position: fixed;
background-color: #262626;
width: 5%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
.Sidebar-Icon {
align-items: center;
font-size: 30px;

}
.Sidebar-Icon .SDIcon {
 text-decoration-line: none;
}
.Sidebar-Icon li {
list-style-type: none;
}
ul.Sidebar-Icon {
cursor: pointer;
display: flex;
padding: 0;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
flex: 1;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}
.Sidebar-Icon li:first-child{
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.Sidebar-Icon li:first-child,
.Sidebar-Icon li:last-child{
margin-bottom:auto;
}
.sb-i{
color: #999AAA !important; // shadow AAABBB
}
```

Html (Angular) Code

```
<div class="Sidebar" [@collapse]="collapse">
<div class="Sidebar-Inner">

<div class="profileimg"></div>

</div>
<ul class="Sidebar-Icon ">    
  <li><a  class="sb-i" (click)="toggleCollapse()">
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v" ></i></a></li>
<li><a class="sb-i"href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
</li>
<li><a class="sb-i"href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-child"></i>
</a></li>
<li><a class="sb-i"href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fab fa-accessible-
icon"></i></a></li>
<li><a class="sb-i"href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></a>
</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

example of the issue (Zoomlevel on 500%):

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you share your complete code? HTML+CSS

Comment: @RohitVerma added what u  asked for

Comment: I'm really confused... you've tagged this as `glyphicons` but the classes you're calling are clearly Font Awesome 5.

Comment: @RobertC my bad. totally forgot about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="Sidebar" [@collapse]="collapse">
    <div class="Sidebar-Inner">

        <div class="profileimg"></div>

    </div>
    <ul class="Sidebar-Icon ">
        <li><a  class="sb-i" (click)="toggleCollapse()">
            <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v" ></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="sb-i" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="sb-i" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-child"></i>
        </a></li>
        <li><a class="sb-i" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fab fa-accessible-
icon"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="sb-i" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #262626;
    width: 5%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.Sidebar-Icon {
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 30px;

}
.Sidebar-Icon .SDIcon {
    text-decoration-line: none;
}
.Sidebar-Icon li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.Sidebar-Icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.Sidebar-Icon li:first-child{
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.Sidebar-Icon li:first-child,
.Sidebar-Icon li:last-child{
    margin-bottom:auto;
}
.sb-i{
    color: #999AAA !important; // shadow AAABBB
}

.sb-i i{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.sb-i svg {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: didnt worked. i tried most of the solution and none worked out

Comment: i do, i am using fontawesome

Comment: fontawesome latest version show svg in browser when you add i tag like 
<i class="far fa-address-book"></i>

Comment: if you check my html code you can see that i am using the fontawesome class as you already described

Comment: still oversized icons. replaced my code with yours*

Comment: you add this link and check
 <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

Comment: you were right :) script import was missing, but one more thing , https://gyazo.com/8d472d01ebd7c21a0ad6b50971c7a6ca this is how it looks like now on full zoom , is it possible to fix the icons on 30px and they wont shrink or grow at all ?

Comment: For this you will need to use @media styling in Css.